# Revert a range of commits in git

Tags: git, revert, range

How can I revert a range of commits in git? From looking at the [gitrevisions](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) documentation, I cannot see how to specify the range I need. For example:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> HEAD
```

I want to do the equivalent of:

```
git revert B-D
```

where the result would be:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F -> HEAD
```

where F contains the reverse of B-D inclusive.

Comment: Towards the end of the gitrevisions(7) page, there is a section headed "SPECIFYING RANGES". How does what you want differ from what's described there?

Comment: The gitrevisions page suggests that 'git revert A..D' will do what I want. However when I try that I get the error "fatal: Cannot find 'A..D'"

Comment: 11 years later but just wanted to say this is a really clear and well-worded question. :muscle:

Comment: See also a sort of inverse corollary to this: [How to cherry-pick multiple commits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1670970/4561887)

Answer (score 252, accepted):

What version of Git are you using?

Reverting multiple commits in only supported in Git1.7.2+: see "[Rollback to an old commit using revert multiple times.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716051/rollback-to-an-old-commit-using-revert-multiple-times)" for more details.
The current [`git revert` man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html) is only for the *current* Git version (1.7.4+).

---

As the [OP Alex Spurling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12149/alex-spurling) reports in the comments:

Upgrading to 1.7.4 works fine.
To answer my own question, this is the syntax I was looking for:

```
git revert B^..D
```

`B^` means "the first parent commit of B": that allows to include `B` in the revert.
See "[`git rev-parse` SPECIFYING REVISIONS section](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#_specifying_revisions)" which include the [`<rev>^`, e.g. `HEAD^`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#git-rev-parse-emltrevgtemegemHEADv1510em) syntax: see more at "[What does the caret (`^`) character mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1956054/6309)")

Note that each reverted commit is committed separately.

[Henrik N](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6962/henrik-n) clarifies in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991594/revert-a-range-of-commits-in-git/4992711#comment16848992_4992711):

```
git revert OLDER_COMMIT^..NEWER_COMMIT
```

As shown below, you can revert without committing right away:

```
git revert -n OLDER_COMMIT^..NEWER_COMMIT
git commit -m "revert OLDER_COMMIT to NEWER_COMMIT"
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer. Upgrading to 1.7.4 works fine. To answer my own question, this is the syntax I was looking for:

git revert B^..D

Comment: genius. thanks. It hadn't occurred to me I need to revert commits in reverse order for the patches to apply, duh. This command shows the way.

Comment: I refer back to this answer often, and it always takes me a while to figure out the order. So to help my future self: `git revert OLDER_COMMIT^..NEWER_COMMIT`

Comment: what does the ^ mean?

Comment: @DustinGetz first parent: see http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions: "A suffix `^` to a revision parameter means the first parent of that commit object".

Comment: You could also then `git rebase -i HEAD~3` (up to the previous `HEAD`) and squash most of the revert commits (in this case the last 2, -D and -C) together into the first one (-B) to have a single revert commit.

Comment: @JorgeOrpinel True. I remember studying the difference between merge squash and rebase in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2427520/6309 in 2010.

Comment: Seems it does not work properly in case of merge conflicts in several commits of the range.

Comment: @ks1322 That is possible. What version of Git are you using?

Comment: I use git version 2.20.1. Seems it stopped on first merge conflict. I had to revert commits and resolve conflicts one by one.

Comment: @ks1322 OK. Resolving conflicts seems necessary, but Git 2.34+ has a better merge algo by default (the ORT one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64950077/6309), which can help.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: this desired range of commits should be able to be shown beforehand, using: `git rev-list OLDER_COMMIT^..NEWER_COMMIT`

Comment: @Life5ign I believe so, yes.

Comment: Interesting. The "commit range" syntax for `git revert` is the same as that for `git cherry-pick`. See here: [How to cherry-pick multiple commits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1670970/4561887)

Comment: @GabrielStaples True: the `<commit>` in [`git revert`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#Documentation/git-cherry-pick.txt-ltcommitgt82308203), et [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#Documentation/git-cherry-pick.txt-ltcommitgt82308203) use [`git revisions`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_specifying_revisions).

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It only reverts the last commit in the given range for some reason. I'm on git `2.39.2 (Apple Git-143)`.

Comment: @trusktr OK. Can you ask a separate question to study that in detail?

Answer (score 38):

**How to revert a range of commits with *one single* revert commit**

If you want to revert commit range B to D (at least in git version 2) in a single commit, you can do:

```bash
git revert -n B^..D
git commit -m "revert the commit range B to D, inclusive"
```

The `-n` (or `--no-commit`) argument tells git to revert the changes done by the commits starting from B's parent commit (excluded) to the D commit (included), but *not* to create any commit with the reverted changes. The revert only modifies the working tree (your active file system) and the index (your staged file section).

Don't forget to commit the changes after running `git revert -n`:

```bash
git commit -m "revert the commit range B to D, inclusive"
```

You can also revert multiple unrelated commits in a single commit, using the same method. For example: to revert B and D but not C:

```bash
git revert -n B D
git commit -m "Revert commits B and D"
```

References:

1. https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html
2. Thanks [Honza Haering](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4045486/honza-haering) for the [correction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991594/revert-a-range-of-commits-in-git/41822306#comment71168561_41822306).
3. From `man git revert`:

   > `-n`, `--no-commit`
   >
   > Usually the command automatically creates some commits with commit log messages stating which commits were reverted. This flag applies the changes necessary to revert the named commits to your working tree and the index, but does not make the commits. In addition, when this option is used, your index does not have to match the `HEAD` commit. The revert is done against the beginning state of your index.
   >
   > This is useful when reverting more than one commits' effect to your index in a row.

Comment: `git revert -n B..D` does not revert commit B, only C and D. 
`git revert -n B^..D` reverts B as well.

Comment: according to git documentation it does.
reference in the post

Comment: If you reffering to this example (which I think is a bit confusing) in the reference: `git revert -n master~5..master~2`, it says fifth latest commit included. But `master~5` is actually 6th latest commit. See [revision selection](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection) in git docs for detailed info about `..` notation :-)

Comment: This is generally a bad idea if you plan to re-apply those commits

Comment: @PatKilg, I don't see how. You can still re-apply the commits one-at-a-time in separate commits if you want, after doing this one, combined revert commit.

Comment: Excellent answer, and exactly what I needed! I need to add in some history (maybe 10 commits) from old versions of our software, with*out* rewriting history, and with*out* changing our `main` branch when I'm done, and this answer is exactly what I need! To perform this, I'm going to wipe the working tree, and copy version 1 of our software into the working tree, then commit it. Then I'll copy in v2, and commit it, then v3, and commit it, etc. etc. until all our history is added. When done, I want a *single* revert commit to undo all of those versions. When done, the `main` branch will be...

Comment: ...exactly how it started, and our software version history will be now available within the repo so we can always `git diff` against it when needed, to see what had changed in the past!

Answer (score 13):

Doing `git revert OLDER_COMMIT^..NEWER_COMMIT` didn't work for me.

I used `git revert -n OLDER_COMMIT^..NEWER_COMMIT` and everything is good. I'm using git version `1.7.9.6`.

Comment: I have had the same issue and fix it using -n, but you should leave ^ with OLDER_COMMIT (git revert -n OLDER_COMMIT^..NEWER_COMMIT).

Comment: @FeelGood why you should leave the ^?

Comment: I had history  A -> B -> C and the goal was to revert B and C. When I run 'git revert -n B..C', only C was reverted. When I used 'git revert -n B^..C', git reverted both commits. Maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: cool, well have to test it but i think in my case worked good (unless i was reverting a 1 commit range lol) i'll modify the answer to include the ^. thanks

Comment: The `-n` or `--no-commit` option will revert all the changes across the range in a single commit, instead of creating a revert commit for every commit in the range. End result is the same, as in, the same changes will be reverted. Just depends how you want your git history to look like.

Comment: @FeelGood the range B..D signifies commits that are reachable from D but not from B. That's why B is not included -- because B is reachable from itself. Using B^..D means commits that are reachable from D but not from B's parent, so B gets included.

Answer (score -2):

Use `git rebase -i` to squash the relevant commits into one. Then you just have one commit to revert.

Comment: If using git rebase, you can simply remove the commits. I think there is a reason not to rebase, like wanting to keep SHA1 of commit F the same.

Comment: Alternatively, squash the reverting commits into one.

Comment: I guess you can squash them on a separate branch, revert that commit, and cherry-pick the reverting commit onto the original branch.