# How do you selectively release a good branch and not a bad branch if the bad branch came first?

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm working specifically within the confines of git-flow here.  It's very clear to me how this would be accomplished with git generally, but git-flow is the thing I'm primarily concerned with here.

Imagine this scenario:

- developer 1 and developer 2 are both working in parallel.
- developer 1 and developer 2 each have many small issues.
- developer 1 finishes his first branch, we'll call it `feature/A`.  `feature/A` is quickly approved and merged to `develop`
- developer 2 finishes his first issue, we'll call it `feature/b`.  `feature/B` is quickly approved and merged to `develop`
- developer 2 now must start `feature/C`.  So he checks out develop, and does `git pull upstream develop` then `git checkout -b feature/C`
- developer 2 finishes `feature/C`. `feature/C` is quickly approved and merged to `develop`

But wait!  There's a problem.  We've discovered a bug from `feature/A` and the release is tomorrow!  We need to release B and C but not A.  How do I do that?  All to the commits from `feature/A` are contained in `feature/C`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to revert `feature/A`: use [`git revert`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert).

You can generate a new commit in `feature/C` which will cancel all commits from `feature/A`.
(You can revert multiple commits, [even a range of commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4992711/6309) that way)
Then you merge `feature/C` to `develop` again.

Comment: As an aside, you'd keep this "within the confines of git-flow" by starting a "feature", call it "revert-feature-A", and then performing the `git revert` on that branch, and then merging that feature. Note that git-flow is a *very* general set of guidelines  that most developers outgrow quite quickly, and not something you *need* to stick to for every given situation. There is no reason to use git-flow to revert feature-A, for example.