# Git, How to make my develop mirror/clone my master branch?

Tags: git, github, gitolite

I had a developer messing up the develop branch for a few weeks now without telling me and pushing the code to the remote server, I ended up after having a lot of meetings would like to replicate/clone/mirror the master branch into my development branch.

Yes I know I will be losing all the development work and that's OK right now.. I need a stable start and clear start that would be master.

So how to make my develop completely replicate/mirror my master branch?

I did the following:

```
git checkout develop
git reset --hard master
git commit -am "head reset"
git push
```

and I got the following error:

> ! [rejected]        develop -> develop (non-fast-forward) error:
>   failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@xxx/project' hint: Updates were
>   rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind hint: its
>   remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') hint:
>   before pushing again. hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git
>   push --help' for details.

so after getting the error I did this:

```
git push --force
```

but then if I do a pull it will pull then all the old code again...  Please help me out

Comment: Is deleting and recreating the branch an option?

Comment: but then all the other programmers are going to have issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but then all the other programmers are going to have issues

All the other programmers will have issue anyway.

You reset `develop` to `master` (the commit shouldn't be needed here), and forced push it.

That means, any other developer will have to:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout develop
git reset origin/develop
```

And then add/merge their current change.

---

> I do a pull it will pull then all the old code again

It should not: the `develop` branch and `master` branch should point to the same point.

---

The other approach would be to [revert the commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4992711/6309) of the `develop` branch, in order to generate a new commit which would cancel them.
The reset is the easier quicker way, but a [`git revert`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) allows to not rewrite anything, and push a new commit.