# remote branching after the fact

Tags: git, repository, branch

Suppose I have worked on a project for a week and committed my changes every day and pushed them to the remote repo:

```
Mo - Tu - We - Th - Fr - Sa - Su   (origin/master)
```

Monday morning I realize that what I wrote on the weekend went in the wrong direction. Is it technically possible to pretend I created a new branch on saturday, like this?

```
Mo - Tu - We - Th - Fr   (origin/master)
                       \
                         Sa - Su   (origin/experimental)
```

If this is technically possible, does it violate the rules of changing public repos?

Comment: It's no problem to do that but you would have to force push master

Answer (score 1):

You can push your current `master` branch as `experimental`:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b experimental
git push -u origin experimental
```

Then you would need to reset and force push master, which can be inconvenient if other contributors have already fetched that branch:

```
git reset --hard master Fr
git push --force
```

Or you could [revert `Sa` and `Su`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4992711/6309), using [`git revert`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert):

```
git revert -n Sa^..Su
# check, then commit
git add .
git commit -m "Revert Sa and Su"
git push
```

That way, you create an additional commit which cancels `Sa` and `Su`, and doesn't requite a `push --force`.

```
Mo - Tu - We - Th - Fr - Re  (origin/master)
                      \
                        Sa - Su   (origin/experimental)
```

Comment: Won't reverting the commits cause issues when merging the branch back into master (similar to reverting a merge commit)?

Comment: @musiKk it might, but if they are many collaborators who have already fetched `origin/master`, it is better than trying to force push.

Comment: I fully agree. I just remember this from the "revert a merge commit" case. You have to remember to re-revert the commits before merging, otherwise the merge ignores these, probably leading to strange conflicts.

Comment: @musiKk you mean https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt? This doesn't seem to be *exactly* the same situation though.

Comment: No, but I think the merge will still ignore the commits that are already present in the history. I'd have to try it out to be 100% sure though.