# Revert all branch specific changes so the branch reflect master

Tags: git

Is it possible to revert all changes made to a specific branch without losing history?

I branched master a long time ago to hide specific features but now this branch has to become the same as master but I need the branch history intact.

`master -> branched -> (revert stripping) -> branched = master`

The *branched* should now reflect **master** although I want a commit in **branched** with all the changes that was needed to get to **master**.

The easiest way I can think of is to copy the sources of **master** and delete/paste files in **branched** but my worry is if this will generate conflicts when later merging from master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit:

The solution from Preuk does not work for me (Git 2.2.1), but those commands work:

```
$ git checkout branched
$ git revert -n master..branched
$ git commit -m "Revert to master"
```

### Initial post:

I would suggest to use `git format-patch` followed by `git am` on a dedicated branch, squash the commits with `git rebase -i`, and then apply the result on the branch `branched`:

1. Create new branch starting from `branched`:

   ```
   $ git checkout branched
   $ git checkout -b tmpbranch
   ```
2. Apply the reversed commits between `master` and `branched`:

   ```
   $ git format-patch -R master..branched --stdout | git am
   ```
3. Squash the commits into a single one:

   ```
   $ git rebase -i branched
   $ # Use the squash command for all commits except the first one
   $ # and set the log message to "Revert to master" for instance.
   ```
4. Then merge and delete the temporary branch `tmpbranch` onto `branched`:

   ```
   $ git checkout branched
   $ git merge tmpbranch
   $ git branch -d tmpbranch
   ```

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for but it keeps telling me that "-m" flag is missing. How do I get the parent number accordingly to http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert? It wont let me use "1" which I understood as the first given branch.

Answer (score 0):

You could try reverting and rebasing from master in squash mode.

First, you would need to revert commit specific to your branch from its inception. To do so, use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4992711/1503505) :

```
git revert OLDER_COMMIT^..NEWER_COMMIT
```

You would then get 1 commit on your satellite branch with all of the changes from master since branch split.

```
git checkout topicbranch
git rebase -i master
```

and select squash for every commit.