# How to reset long running git branch to master?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, undo

We have a `master` branch and many short living feature branches that get merged into `master` after the customers have accepted the changes.

In addition to that we have long living environment branches for the user acceptance system and the production system, named `stage` and `prod`, that are originally branched from master.

Our workflow looks like that:

- develop feature on feature branch
- merge feature branch into `stage`
- wait for customer acceptance
- on acceptance merge to `master`
- `master` gets merged into `prod` the next day

Customer acceptance can take short to very long, so there are several "features" living on `stage` that are either waiting for acceptance or abandoned. Because if the customer does *not* accept the change we do not merge the feature to `master` but sadly it lives on on `stage` like a zombie :)

**Now the question(s):**

How would we reset the branch `stage` to current `master` without losing the ability to merge the feature branches that are still waiting for acceptance to `stage` again? The goal here is to get rid of the abandoned "features".

Is this possible without altering history and force-push?

Comment: To clarify: we can of course rewrite history and force-push if there is no other option.

Comment: There are many commits and merge commits in the history. The merge commits seem to be a problem that prevent `git revert master^..stage`.

Comment: have you get the answer which help you to solve the problem? If yes, please mark it. And it will help others who have similar questions.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT oh yes thanks for reminding me of this ticket! Sorry.

Comment: So I added what we did as an answer with more details. Thanks for all suggestions, They helped a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what we ended up doing was to just delete the branch `stage` and create a new branch `stage` from the current `master`. This way all unmerged features are removed, and because all the feature branches still exists they are also still mergeable to the new `stage` branch.

So we merged some branches that we know are currently waiting for customer acceptance back to `stage` and got rid of all the abandoned features.

Answer (score 1):

Without rewriting history, the only thing that I can think of would be to revert those commits from the abandoned features.

Comment: Yes thats a possibility. But the problem is there are many many merges and it would take a lot of time to sort this out. Its two years of work by 20+ people... was hoping for an easier solution :)

Comment: Ah, that is quite a lot of things to revert. I think that this might be what you're looking for then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29768207/revert-all-branch-specific-changes-so-the-branch-reflect-master

Comment: I will have a look, many thanks already! Sounds like this would be it if it works :)

Comment: Did not work. `Commit ... is a merge but no -m option was given. revert failed`. I tried this: `git revert -n master..branched`. I will try the "initial post" steps now.

Comment: "initial post" did not work either. There are several errors, I will try to understand them and maybe get it working.

Answer (score 1):

If you merge features into `stage` with true merges, it's easy to revert those merges.  Simply run `git revert` on the merge commit, with the appropriate `-m` argument (usually `-m 1`).

If you merge features into `stage` by copying commits or by fast-forwarding, it's more difficult, as you must revert each commit.  You can give `git revert` a *range* of commits to revert, and it will do all of them in the appropriate—i.e., last-to-first—order.  Note that ranges of the form `A..B` mean "everything reachable from `B`, except for everything reachable from `A`", and since `A` is clearly reachable from itself, this *excludes* commit `A` itself.  Hence `1234567..fedcba9` includes commit `fedcba9` and earlier commits back to `1234567` but *excludes* 1234567 itself.

If you merge features into `stage` using `git merge --squash`, this copies all the commits into one big (but independent) commit, so that you would again simply run `git revert` on the one copied commit (without `-m` as it is not a merge commit).

(Note that however you revert these, if you eventually discover that you want the feature after all, it's a bit painful.)

Comment: Thanks for this, I will try it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

Since all approved features are merge into master, so the first unmerged commit on stage is abandoned feature. Assume F1, F2 and F3 are the living features waiting for customer acceptance on stage branch. And F1 is abandoned feature and F2, F3 are accept features. So it need to get rid of F1 on stage.

```
          C-----…-----D---F1---F2---F3  stage
         /             \
A---…---B---…---E---…---G       master
                \        \
                 F----…----H    prod
```

You can use below commands:

```
git checkout stage
git rebase --onto <commit id for D> <commit id for F1> stage
```

then the structure will look like:

```
          C-----…-----D ---F2’---F3’  stage
         /             \
A---…---B---…---E---…---G       master
                \        \
                 F----…----H    prod
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I will try it as soon as I can.

Comment: I tried this and it works, but there are (were) too many merged branches.