# GitHub - revert in-between commit

Tags: github, commit, revert

We have some commit on git which was wrongly added
We have done some more commits also above that wrong commit.
Now I want to remove that commit without affecting on other commits.

Is there any way to remove it?

Please guide

Answer (score 3):

> remove that commit without affecting on other commits

Use [`git revert`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert): that will create a new commit which will cancel the ones you don't want to see. You will be able to push that new commit.
You can [revert a range of commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4992711/6309).

But that means the data from those "wrong comimts" remains in the history.

Answer (score 1):

You can revert any commit, regardless of where it is in your history. Just type `git revert <sha>`.

You may have to do a conflict resolution if there are conflicts.