# Git recreate previous state

Tags: git, github

I have a git repository on GitHub.
My last three commits are changes, that I now want to rollback, but **keep** them in the git history.

```
Master-Branch:

- HEAD: 3. Change; removed one of added files, added new line in main.js
- -1  : 2. Change; removed line in one of added files
- -2  : 1. Change; Added two files
- -3  : Stuff <-- This is the status of the project that I want
```

- Now, I tried `$ git revert <COMMIT-SHA>` but this only resets changes for that specific commit and ignores all the other commits that happend in that time.
- `$git reset <COMMIT-SHA>` throws away all the changes that I made.

Is there a simple way to recreate the state of a specific commit, push it as a new commit and effectively get your previous state without going through all changes manually?

Comment: `git revert <1-SHA> <2-SHA> <3-SHA>`? It sounds like you want a commit that undoes the last 3 commits, not the 4th (which is what `git revert <4-SHA>` did).

Comment: If the branch in question is published on the repo _and_ shared by others, then `git revert` might be the best option here.

Comment: `$git revert <1-SHA> <2-SHA> <3-SHA>` so if I had, say 50 commits I needed to provide all 50 commit shas? @jonrsharpe
Is there a shortcut?

Comment: If that _is_ what you're trying to do, dupe is https://stackoverflow.com/q/1463340/3001761.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have seen your question as well but the guy asking wants to remove `.e. I want B, C, D, and HEAD to disappear `. I want to keep those changes in history, or do I misunderstand?

Comment: They're explicitly asking how to revert rather than rewrite history, and various of the answer use the `git revert` command, so I think you do, yes.

Comment: Note that "closed as duplicate" does not imply that the other question is better, or yours should go away, or anything of the sort: it just means that these are two different ways to ask the same question, in the end. Leaving yours in existence as a closed duplicate will let others find the question using your wording.

Answer (score 1):

As I explain in "[Revert a range of commits in git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4992711/6309)", what you need is

```
git revert commit3..HEAD
```

It will revert everything *after* commit 3, up to HEAD commit, making one new commit reverting the previous commits (except commit3)

So this is not so about reverting multiple commits, than it is about reverting a *range* of commits.

Answer (score -1):

Kinda works:

`$ git revert --no-commit <COMMIT SHA>..`

puts me in git revert mode, change by change, so I can have a commit for each change that happened