# How to make a previous commit the head of the master branch while ignoring everything from the most recent merge into master?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Current scenario:

- Developer 1 has done some work and pushed to master and deployed.
- Developer 2 has done some work while developer 1 was working on his own tasks, pushed to master, and didn't deploy yet.

The catch: Developer 2's work would break production if deployed.

So in BitBucket, it looks kinda like this:

```
31 jan merge dev2 branch into master
31 Jan commit_hash_for_dev2
25 jan commit hash_for_dev2
21 jan commit hash_for_dev1 (currently what is in production)
15 jan commit hash_for_dev2
12 jan commit hash_for_dev2
```

Do I do:

```
git checkout hash_for_dev1 . (where the dot makes it the head)
git commit -m "reverting dev2 changes)
git push origin master
open a pull request
```

How do I bring the master branch head to dev1 latest commit and ignore everything dev2 merged ?

Answer (score 1):

The idea would be to use git revert, in order to [revert a range of commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4992711/6309)

```
git revert -m 1 OLDER_COMMIT^..NEWER_COMMIT
```

That would create a new commit, with the negative image of dev2 most recent commits.
You can push that and make a pull request.

Comment: Interesting, but what if there were multiple commits ?

Comment: Range of commits means multiple commits. Or did you mean multiple ranges? That would imply multiple reverts, from the oldest range to the most recent one.

Comment: I tried that but got this mainline was specified but commit 33esdfdw3... is not a merge

Comment: @stacknoob Then try without `-m 1`.

Comment: That won't work because one of the commits is a merge. 
It goes like this: 1(newest commit - merge), 2 (regular commit), 3 (regular commit), 4 (oldest commit - merge). And I am trying to revert 1 to 4

Comment: @stacknoob So maybe try to revert first the oldest commit, using `-m1`, then revert the other ones, without `-m 1`.