# Revert a merged pull request in github

Tags: git, pull-request

I have accidentally merged a pull request and pushed the changes to the remote repository, by using the command while staying in the destination branch

```
git pull origin <source branch>
git push
```

Now PR is saying it's merged[image]

Also there is not any commit related to this merge.

Revert button is not visible in the closed Pull Request, I can't use the git reset command as there were more than 50 commits in the PR.

How can I revert that merge of PR?

Comment: What does this mean: "I can't use the git reset command as there were more than 50 commits in the PR." If you can force push, then you could just hard reset the branch to how it was before the merge and force push it out.

Comment: If you can reset, I'd probably lean towards that, as described in [Easterwood's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77945691/184546). Whether you can do this is dependent on whether you are able to force push without messing up everyone else. If you can't reset, then you need to revert the range of 119 commits. Something like `git revert -n commit1^..commit119` followed by a commit, as described in [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4991594/184546). Just make sure you use the `-n` option or else you'll end up with 119 individual revert commits.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer:** *Only apply the following instruction if you are sure that no other users are using the history of the remote repository that you want to change.*

You can reset `git reset --hard ...` your local branch to a commit before the `git pull...` and push the result via `git push --force` to the remote repository. You probably have to enable this on the remote repository side.

With [git-reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) you can find the SHA-1 of the previous state.

For example:

```bash
git status # check for any uncommitted status, get lost with following cli
git reset --hard a2de345 # reset to a state before the git pull
git push --force # forces git to overwrite the current history on the remote repository
```

Before pushing the new history to the remote repository you could save the remote to a separate branch in case something get lost.

Comment: All warnings about rewriting published history apply, of course.

Comment: Of course :). Before pushing it to the remote you could check your history if it fits.

Comment: Are we talking about the same warnings? I mean: published history can be pulled by others. Those who did before the history was rewritten will suffer severe headaches when they are confronted with the rewritten history later.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't aware your not the only one making commits to this repository. I that case my solution isn't a good one.

Answer (score 1):

Pulling the remote branch into your destination branch brought the changes from that branch into your destination. You say there's no merge commit. That means a fast-forward merge was done. In that case, your destination branch pointer moved forward to the latest commit on your remote branch.
Check your commit history and get the commit id of your last commit on the remote branch (say abc12345).
To revert that commit: `git revert -m 1 abc12345`

This will create a revert commit and cancel all the changes you made on the destination branch. Don't forget to push the reverted commit.
After you take back the changes on your repo, you can switch to the remote branch and keep working on it. But you have to create a new PR on Github later.

Comment: How will this work if there is no merge commit?

Comment: ***'-m 1'*** option tells Git that we want to go back to the state of the first parent before joining two branches together. Git is clever enough to figure out how to do it.

Comment: But there is no merge commit. So `-m 1` will have no effect and do the same as without it. Only the top commit will be reverted; the other 118 commits will not be reverted.

Comment: You should try and see for yourself instead of theory crafting. You will see it's working perfectly.

Comment: Have you tried running your command on a commit that is *not* a merge commit? If yes, how many commits' changes are reverted?

Comment: Maybe we're not envisioning the same starting point here? I'm thinking OP is starting from the scenario where the PR's source, PR's destination, and local branch are all identical. Reverting the tip commit of any of those 3 branches will have the same effect, which is to revert only the 119th commit (the most recent).